# how to setup kismet.conf on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Kismet on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine as apt-get install kismet
every thing seems to work fine.

but when I launch it I see following error

kismet

```
Launching kismet_server: //usr/bin/kismet_server
Suid priv-dropping disabled.  This may not be secure.
No specific sources given to be enabled, all will be enabled.
Non-RFMon VAPs will be destroyed on multi-vap interfaces (ie, madwifi-ng)
Enabling channel hopping.
Enabling channel splitting.
NOTICE: Disabling channel hopping, no enabled sources are able to
change channel.
Source 0 (addme): Opening none source interface none...
FATAL: Please configure at least one packet source.  Kismet will not
function if no packet sources are defined in kismet.conf or on the
command line.  Please read the README for more information about
configuring Kismet.
Kismet exiting.
Done.
```

I followed this guide 
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/kismet-an-802-11-wireless-network-detector-sniffer-and-intrusion-detection-system.html#more-1776

how ever in kismet.conf I am not clear with following line

```
source=none,none,addme
```

as to what should I change this to.

lspci -vnn shows

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:000c]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information <?>
    Capabilities: [e8] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting <?>
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, ssb
```

and

iwconfig shows

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"WIKUCD"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <00:43:92:21:H5:09>
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power:24 dBm   
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Managementmode:All packets received
          Link Quality=1/5  Signal level=-81 dBm  Noise level=-90 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:169  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

So what should I be putting in place of

```
 source=none,none,addme
```

with  output I mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Kismet Readme](http://www.kismetwireless.net/documentation.shtml#readme)

> WL (Linux, Intel)

```
  Broadcom has released a binary version of their drivers called WL.
  These drivers are incapable of monitor mode, and cannot be used with
  Kismet.  Kismet will attempt to autodetect them and report this to the 
  user.  Users of Broadcom cards should use the b43 or b43xx in-kernel
  drivers.
```

So try with

```
source=bcm4312,none,kbr0
```

I think that should work.

Comment: As addition to the quote: there are some reverse engineered drivers that might work with your card. Check the section "Chipsets known to NOT WORK:"
in the link Bharat provided.